# How to separate the custom build (.next) folder from the source directory and run it independently?

Tags: build, next.js

In compiler language like C, when you build a project the output file is independent of source code. I've written a next.js project but when I build (next build) the project and then move the build folder to another directory the run it (npm start) many errors will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Next.js only supports static HTML project to use the dist folder independently. See [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) for the detail.